# Dragging the div without dragging the whole browser(mobile browser)

Tags: jquery, mobile-browser

I did a draggable div on the mobile browsers with touchstart, touchmove and touchend, but i have one problem.
When I drag the div, the whole screen is moving, how can I do that when I am touching the div and I am moving my finger, the screen will not move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind an event to document for browser to stop its default behavior.

```
$(document).bind('touchmove' , function()
{
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this library which is working very well on mobile : http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Comment: I prefer not to use another library, i want to do it myself.